# Cannot Access Element in Array of Emails Addresses

Tags: c#, arrays, mailmessage

Here is my code for the `Message.To.Add`:

```
MailMessage mailmessage = new MailMessage();
string mailFrom;
mailFrom = "PropertyLossForm";
mailmessage.From = new MailAddress("propertyloss@brixmor.com", mailFrom);

string mailTo;
mailTo = txtEmailAddress.Text;
mailTo = Strings.Replace(mailTo, ",", "");

//Separates the received string into and array of email addresses
Array mailToArray = null;
mailToArray = Strings.Split(Strings.Trim(mailTo), " ");

//Adds all of the recipients to the MailMessage
for (int i = mailToArray.GetLowerBound(0); i <= mailToArray.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
{
    //Response.Write(mailToArray(i) + "<br>")
    mailmessage.To.Add(mailToArray(i));
}
```

It's telling me `mailmessage.To.Add(mailToArray(i));` mailArray is being used as a method.  Not sure what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to change `Array mailToArray =` to `string[] mailToArray`.

`mailmessage.To.Add(mailToArray`**(i)**`);` should then be `mailmessage.To.Add(mailToArray`**[i]**`);` , the indexer for arrays. `()` next to an identifier are used to imply a method, while `[]` are used to 'index into' an array and grab a specific element. Though is a normal operator and be overridden, so theoretically it could even be treated as a method (don't do this.)

Comment: Ok, I'm still lost here.  What should I do then? Or what is it that I need to do in order for this to work properly?

Comment: `mailmessage.To.Add(mailToArray(i));`
should be
`mailmessage.To.Add(mailToArray[i]);`

Comment: Also, on your for each loop why don't you use `for (int i = 0; i < mailToArray.Length; i++)` ?

Comment: Still does not work.  Now I am getting "Cannot apply indexing [] to an expression of type 'System.Array'

Comment: Oh crud, you said Array, not string[]. Updating answer.